# Why isn't this anchor tag functioning?

Tags: html, css, debugging, anchor

This is kind of weird and I feel like it is probably some subtle css rule that I can't figure out.  If you look on the linked page at where the blog posts are, the thumbnails for each post are inside an a tag and then inside a div yet when you hover them no link is registering to be able to click the image.

http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/?page_id=72

Comment: Seems to work for me. When I hover over the thumbnail, the image changes. When I click, I go to the post. OS X 10.6.8, latest Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The floated div was outside the non floated div.